# Regex/preg_match - get text between string and email address

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm extracting data from emails. I have pieces of text like this:

```
Eg. 1: some standard text.   Bugs Bunny bugs@gmail.com 0411111111 more standard text 
Eg. 2: some standard text.   Bugs The Bunny bugs@gmail.com 0411111111 more standard text
Eg. 3: some standard text.   Bugs Bunny bugs.bunny@gmail.com 0411111111 more standard text
Eg. 4: some standard text.   Bugs bugs.bunny@gmail.com +6141 111 111 more standard text
```

As you can see, there is a name, email and phone number that I want to extract.
The email should be easy enough, and I'm sure I can work out the phone options but how could I get the name?

I know the logic is: get the text after `some standard text.` and before the the first non-space-separated string before the `@`, but how?

This is my starting point `(?<=some standard text.   )(.*?)(?=@)`

This gives me a result with a group `(?<=some standard text.   )(.*?)(?:[\w-\.]+)@` so I think I'm on the right path.

I'm using php.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by `a full match`? 2. Then `some standard text.` is always the same and always end with a dot?

Comment: Here is a quick version/example I came up with: `(?<=some standard text.   )(.*?) ([^\s]+@[^\s]+) (\+?\d+(?:\s\d+)*)` (https://regex101.com/r/Wjz66g/1). It's not perfect, but it does follow along the same lines as what you were doing and might work enough.

Comment: @addons_zz - I've just educated myself on groups, so I'm going to edit the question slightly.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - love it! Please post that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick version/example I came up with:

```
(?<=some standard text. )(.*?) ([^\s]+@[^\s]+) (\+?\d+(?:\s\d+)*)
```

regex101.com/r/Wjz66g/1

It's not perfect, but it does follow along the same lines as what you were doing and might work enough.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this, you can test it on: https://regex101.com/r/A29hjE/8

```
(?x) # Here we are entering the the free space mode

# Here we assure the spaces are not matched by the `[\w ]+` group
(?:\.\s+)

# Here we are matching for the guys name, before its email address
([\w ]+(?:\w+))\s+

# Here we match the email
(\w[^\s]+@[^\s]+)\s+

# Here  we match the telephone number
(\+?[\d ]+)(?!\w)
```